# Reload Single ViewController on Awakening of App

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a viewcontroller that needs to be reloaded when the app comes out of the background. I would just need this single viewcontroller to completely reload. I dont need to do anything If the app becomes active on any of the other viewcontrollers. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the view controller register for the `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` notification or perhaps the `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`.

In `viewDidLoad` you can do:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(foregrounded) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
```

In `dealloc` you need to unregister:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
```

And you need to implement the `foregrounded` method:

```
- (void)foregrounded {
    // app now in the foreground - do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your unique view controller have a unique name ?

If no, then add for each viewcontroller a name.

When app is going to background, then save name of active viewcontroller into [NSUserDefaults](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/&ei=Idf9UOWwBeWj4gTyvoGABw&usg=AFQjCNEAV7tJh-DYMhrMXdIrXEb9uu4mBg&sig2=AmzsfqKcOt3eHDtBk5Z8AQ&bvm=bv.41248874,d.bGE)

When app is restoring to foreground, then check your saved viewcontroller name. If this is your unique viewcontroller, then do a reloading.

Hope this will help to you